# Include middle table in many to many association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 models,

> User, Course, CourseRole

. They are many to many relationship through

> CourseUser

I want to know role of a user in a specific course and I'm using this raw query:

```
const queryRoles = `SELECT "roleName" FROM course_roles cr 
                    JOIN course_users cu ON cr.id = cu."roleId"
                    WHERE "userId"=${tokenData.id} AND "courseId"=${courseId}`;

const role = await db.query(queryRoles, { type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

But I want to using sequelize and I try this:

```
const role = await CourseRole.findOne({
    attributes: ["roleName"],
    include: [{ model: CourseUser, where: { userId: tokenData.id } }]
  });
```

But I get an error:

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: course_users is not associated to
>   course_roles!

```
User.belongsToMany(Course, {
  as: 'courses',
  through: CourseUser,
  foreignKey: 'userId'
});
Course.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: 'organization_users',
  through: CourseUser,
  foreignKey: 'courseId'
});
CourseRole.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: 'organization_users',
  through: CourseUser,
  foreignKey: 'roleId'
});
User.belongsToMany(CourseRole, {
  as: 'course_roles',
  through: CourseUser,
  foreignKey: 'userId'
});
```

So is there any way to do with Sequelize? Thank you

Comment: First of all, you probably have a SQL injection vulnerability in your raw SQL query (you concatenate some inputs with your SQL query). Use this https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements

Comment: Can you provide your Sequelize models?